# Package manager issue after installing phusion passenger

Tags: package-management

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I installed phusion passenger in my machine using the following commands.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
echo 'deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo apt-get update
```

The installation is successful and I am also able to run passenger. But I am able to see the below error related to my package manager.

[image]

Because of this error software updater application is not working.

Can anybody help to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to run sudo apt-get update and post the out put in your question

Comment: The error message is clear, no need to do that.

Comment: You are wrong the error proberly is unmet dependancies, you are only reading a small part of the whole error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this command:

`sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list`

Which basically renders the file inaccessible to every user beyond root. You should set read permissions to this file for everyone:

`sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list`

For more details on `chmod` check the [Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/chmod.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

The package manager can't open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list`, the reason being "permission denied".

Check the ownership and permissions on the other files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory (type `sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`)  and change those of passenger.

list if they are different (i.e. if they do not have the same owner and / or group and permissions (which are the `rwx` letters)).

Comment: This is not very helpful, you did not tell how to check the permissions and in his question he said sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list this means the owner can read and write the file only, so permissions are fine

Comment: I'm not going to write "An introduction to Linux" here, google has enough information on how to check permissions and change them if needed.

Comment: It is recommend by site admin to at least copy paste the relivent info to the answer. This is a comment at best not a answer

Comment: I added some information to my answer to improve it, although I still think that explaining ls -l is out of place here.

Comment: I changed my vote, this is much more useful

Comment: Thank you for the help and useful discussion. I am marking the other answer as correct because it is more close to the solution with the command to be executed.